# Meteor's cordova: geolocation plugin doesn't work on mobile

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I'm deploying my Meteor (1.2.0.2) app to an Android device.

I installed the plugin by

```
 meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-geolocation@1.0.0
```

> Added Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-geolocation@1.0.0.

I used the plugin by:

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p){ // onSuccess
            console.log(p);
        }, function(e){
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
```

On desktop works perfectly (print p as Geolocation object) but on mobile it just ignores the callbacks (both success and errors).

I tested it in Chrome DevTools (**chrome://inspect**) by setting breakpoints. It steps until .getCurrentPosition call but then (either step over or step in) just skips both callbacks (and If I set a breakpoint within them, they are just not hit).

I even tried

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p){ console.log(p);
```

both on Desktop console (works)

```
undefined
Geolocation { ... }
```

and mobile (does **not** work)

```
undefined
// nothing else is printed
```

Maybe has it something to do with app's permissions?

**EDIT**: I verified **AndroidManifest.xml** and the permissions are actually set by the plugin:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: what version of android are you running? Are you using the crosswalk package or are you using the system webview? Also, in terms of debugging, please check your `adb logcat` to see whether there were errors, they are *not* thrown to the console.

Comment: I'm not using crosswalk but I read there are compatibility issues. I'll try logcat. thank you

Comment: I tried with crosswalk. same issue. I'm deploing to Android 5.0.
I tried with adb logcat but I can't figure out how to detect the error  / filter by package (seems not possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dragonmnl,

## [GPS is unreliable](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/googleMapExamples/wiki/GPSisUnreliable.md).

You did not talk about timeout, I must assume you have NOT set the timeout long enough. Try setting it to about 20 seconds -- as a minimum.

If your readings are poor, or you are timing out

- go outside
- make sure you have a clear view of all horizons (nothing blocking the view)
- walk in a big circle, about 15ft in diameter

In about 30-45 seconds you should have a reading.
This will make sense when you read the link I gave you.

Jesse

Comment: well, this is about Cordova, not GPS itself. I assume Cordova should at least print something, even it was a a completely wrong position (which is what Google Maps app does sometimes before gpx fix).
Aparently restarting my device solved.

Comment: @dragonmnl, If you read [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation), there is a timeout. If the geolocation lookup fails, the *geolocationError()* callback is made after the timeout. If you decode the *error.code* and the *error.message* return via *geolocationError()* callback, then you will see a message about the exact reason for the timeout.  If the geolocation is successful and NO data is returned, then it is a bug.  -- The *timeout* is passed via the **geolocationOptions**.

Comment: It can be tedious, if you have never worked with GPS before. Best of Luck