# Cordova and Geolocation Geolocation

Tags: angularjs, cordova, geolocation, wifi, offline

I have a Cordova application to save the current location of users in Indexeddb to work in offline environment.
I'm using the following code to get the current position.

```
var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
  $cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude
      var long = position.coords.longitude
      //Save data to indexeddb
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });
```

The code is working fine. I'm able to get the current position of the user.
Doing some testing on streets without internet connection, I noticed that several times the application saves information about a place in Brazil(I'm in Australia). I'm able to get the same position when I turn the wifi off.

Why is it happening? and What is the best way to this behavior in the application?

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [GPS is unreliable](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/googleMapExamples/wiki/GPSisUnreliable.md).

I answer this question or very similar ones every day. Here is one from yesterday.

[Meteor's cordova: geolocation plugin doesn't work on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995194/meteors-cordova-geolocation-plugin-doesnt-work-on-mobile/33051763#33051763)

There are ALOT of misconceptions about GPS and geolocation. Garmin and Google both do the development world a great disservice by pretending that nothing is wrong. Read the first link, and you'll see the answers are provide by Garmin. But if you read the Garmin original document, and not the part I lifted, you'll see the problem.

*(Added 2015-Oct-13)* For others that may read this in the future I am adding this bit from [the original Garmin document](http://www8.garmin.com/aboutGPS/). This is AN OUT AND OUT LIE, but it gets sold as the truth. Read the Garmin document further down and you'll how they cover their butts (arse).

> ### How accurate is GPS?
>
> Today's GPS receivers are extremely accurate, thanks to their parallel multi-channel design. Our 12 parallel channel receivers are quick to lock onto satellites when first turned on, and they maintain strong locks, even in dense foliage or urban settings with tall buildings. (...)

FWIW: there are more GPS professional on [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap), if you need more answers.